# Powershell Output Filter

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script where I can run an EXE on a remote maching to stop processes and then reboot the server.  I have everything I think I need but the output for the IP Addresses is coming up as @{ipaddress=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx}.  It is telling me there is an error in my ip address of the server.  Here is what I got.

```
$action = "reboot"

function LoadServerList {
    param([string]$sFileName);

    $aServers = Import-Csv $sFileName | Where-Object { !($_.servername.StartsWith('#')) -and ($_.servername -ne ""); };
    $aServers |  Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name status -Value "unknown";

    return $aServers;
}

$IPADDRESS = Import-Csv -path D:\Scripts\RebootSequence\LABIPAddress.csv | Where-Object { !($_.ipaddress.StartsWith('#')) -and ($_.ipaddress -ne ""); }

$CMD = 'icadmin'
$arg1 = 'tv'
$arg2 = 'admin'
$arg3 = 'admin1'
$arg4 = 'D:\Avaya\IC73\bin\icadmin.exe'
$arg5 = '$SRVIP'

& $CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $IPADDRESS $arg4
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this:

```
$IPADDRESS = Import-Csv -path D:\Scripts\RebootSequence\LABIPAddress.csv | Where-Object { !($_.ipaddress.StartsWith('#')) -and ($_.ipaddress -ne ""); }
```

to this:

```
$IPADDRESS = Import-Csv -path D:\Scripts\RebootSequence\LABIPAddress.csv | Where-Object { !($_.ipaddress.StartsWith('#')) -and ($_.ipaddress -ne ""); } | Select-Object -Expand ipaddress
```